# Random Forest Regression in scikit-learn with criterion MAE instead of MSE is ~150 times slower

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I'm trying to use Random Forest Regression with `criterion = mae` (mean absolute error) instead of `mse` (mean squared error).

It have very significant influence on computation time.

Roughly it takes **6 min** (for `mae`) instead of **2.5 seconds** (for `mse`). About 150 time slower.

Why?

What can be done to decrease computation time?

P.S. the similar happens for the Decision Tree.
Not as significant difference, but approximately the same ration per tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a well-known problem. See [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9553) and [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9626).

Long story short:

- with `mae`, updating the loss takes `O(n)`;
- with `mse`, updating the loss takes `O(1)`.